# Recursive function with for in Mathematica does not work

Tags: recursion, for-loop, wolfram-mathematica

Why does this recursive function not work?

**Code:**

```
Clear[i];
Clear[v];
final= 4;

Recursion = Function[{v},
   For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,
      Print["Current level ", v ];
      Print["Try: ", i];
      If[v == final,
         Print["End"];, 
         Recursion[v + 1]; (*else-case*)
      ];
      Print["Back! i:", i];
   ];
]

Recursion[1];
```

**Out:**

0: Current level 1

1: Try: 1

2: Current level 2

3: Try: 1

4: Current level 3

5: Try: 1

6: Current level 4

7: Try: 1

8: End

9: Back! i:1

10: Current level 4

11: Try: 2

12: End

13: Back! i:2

14: Back! i:3

15: Back! i:4

16: Back! i:5

**Heeelp**

In the 14th line, "i" should be =2, current level: 3 and try: 2.. then i=1, then i=2.. like a binary tree.

Why is this happening?!

Comment: Format your code as code.  See the little icons above the text editor box when you write your question ?  Use the one that looks a bit like this {}.

Comment: I formatted your code for you, but please do it yourself next time.  Read:  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Your iterator `i` is getting incremented inside the recursion, which is why it is counting to 5, higher than its set limit of 2.

You can make `i` a function of `v` to make it behave separately in each recursion, i.e.

```
final = 4;
Recursion = Function[v,
   For[i[v] = 1, i[v] <= 2, i[v]++,
    Print["Current level ", v];
    Print["Try: ", i[v]];
    If[v == final, Print["End"], Recursion[v + 1]];
    Print["Back! i[", v, "]:", i[v]]]];
Recursion[1]
```

This should make it easier for you to see what is happening, although I think you will need to restructure your code when you *do* see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris observes you need to localize `i` within the function, but I recommend you use `Module` to localize `i`.  `v` is already localized by `Function` itself so you do not need `Clear`.  Also, avoid starting user function names with a capital letter, as by convention those are reserved for system functions.

```
final = 4;

recursion =
  Function[{v},
   Module[{i},
    For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,
     Print["Current level ", v];
     Print["Try: ", i];
     If[v == final, Print["End"], recursion[v + 1]];
     Print["Back! i:", i];
  ]]];

recursion[1];
```

Beyond this, the problem doesn't appear to require `For` and would be better written with `Do`.  Also, you may want to choose a different structure: either a function defined with `DownValues` (meaning `f[x_] := ...` rather than `f = Function[...]`), or a `Function` using `Slot` (`#`) where `#0` can be used for recursion.  I will illustrate both methods for you.

#### DownValues

```
recursion2[v_Integer] :=
  Do[
   Print["Current level ", v];
   Print["Try: ", i];
   If[v == final, Print["End"], recursion2[v + 1]];
   Print["Back! i:", i],
   {i, 2}
  ]
```

#### Pure Function with `Slot`

Here `#` (also written `#1`) represents the single parameter of the function, and `#0` is used to represent the function itself.  See [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) for more.

```
recursion3 =
 Do[
   Print["Current level ", #];
   Print["Try: ", i];
   If[# == final, Print["End"], #0[# + 1]];
   Print["Back! i:", i],
   {i, 2}
 ] &;
```